# Google sheets: can I write whole worksheet in one request?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets

I wrote a script in JS (node) that does some stuff with data from several sheets and produces a summary in a new worksheet. The summary has over 3K rows. First, I've tried a simple save-per-row approach:

```
for(let row of rowsForSummary)
    await dataSheetForSummary.addRow(row)
```

but that generates too many requests and after ~70 successful ones another fails with status 429 (`Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Write requests' and limit 'Write requests per minute per user' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com'`).

As a simple workaround, I've added a loop with progress reporting (well, it's in TypeScript actually but that doesn't matter):

```
let successCount = 0
const reportProgress = () => console.log(`saved ${successCount} out of ${rowsForSummary.length}`)
for(let row of rowsForSummary) {
    let success = false
    while(!success) {
        try {
            await dataSheetForSummary.addRow(row as any)
            success = true
            successCount++
        } catch(e) {
            // deal with requests-per-minute limit:
            if(e.response?.status == 429) {
                // wait 60 seconds
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 60*1000))
                reportProgress()
                // retry
                continue
            } else {
                console.error('failed to save row', e)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this looks and works awkwardly: I have to wait a considerable amount of time, has some extra lines and logic. I can't help asking "**can I save the whole thing (worksheet) instead of saving each row separately?**" but haven't found a proper method, at least in [node wrapper docs](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/classes/google-spreadsheet-worksheet). Can you point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, while writing this, I've found the proper method and it's pretty simple:

```
await dataSheetForSummary.addRows(rowsForSummary)
```

Yeah, that's a usual thing: writing a question properly directs to finding solution; I'll post this so that one googling for a solution can find it faster.